# How to create a triangle made of asterisk characters?

Tags: python

I am trying to print a triangle made of asterisk (*) separated by spaces.

If n = 4, it should look like:

```
*
* *
* * *
* * * *
```

This is the code I have:

```
n = 4
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    for j in range(i):
        print("*")
```

This is the result I get:

```
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
```

I would very appreciate what is wrong with my code...

Comment: You aren't taking into account the fact that print adds a newline every time it's called.

Comment: I have seen this question so many times that I do not see any contribution to continue answering it.

Comment: You can one line it like so, just for fun: print('\n'.join(['*' * i for i in range(n + 1)]))

Answer (score 3):

`print()` adds a newline to your string each time.
It is easier to multiply the `*` with the number of times you would like to see it:

```
n = 4
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    print("* " * i)
```

Output:

```
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * *
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 4
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    lvl = ""
    for j in range(i):
        lvl += "* "
    print(lvl)
```

You need to aggregate the level of the triangle to print.

*edit :*

if you don't want spaces at the end of the line :-/

```
n = 4
for i in range(1, n+1):
    print( " ".join([c for c in '*' * i]))
```

Comment: note this will have an extra space on the end of each line

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built-in "end" parameter:

```
n = 4
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    for j in range(i):
        print("*", end=" ")
    print()
```